# Localhost for django not loading after creating table in sqlite

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am new to python and Django.I have installed Django 1.5.1 and python 2.7.My OS is windows 7.I am doing coding in eclipse.I have typed `python manage.py runserver` in windows powershell and started the server.then I changed the server port number to 8080 by the command `python manage.py runserver 8080`.Both conditions worked initially.I am trying to use sqlite database.I have  typed `python manage.py syncdb` for creating tables.It asks for a superuser and somehow i didn't type any password and operation got failed.I have seen in [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) that use `.schema` for viewing the tables created.My issues are:

1. I am unable to view the tables created .I think I am wrong in the usage of .schema command
2. When I reload the `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`page,it didnt get connected even after restarting the wamp server.
   My settings.py is like this

   ```
   ADMINS = (
   # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
   )
   MANAGERS = ADMINS
   DATABASES = {
   'default': {
   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
   'NAME': 'C:\\Eclipse\\workspace\\mysite\\src\\sqlite.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
   # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
   'USER': '',
   'PASSWORD': '',
   'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
   'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
     }
   }

   # Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
   # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

   # Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
   # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
   # although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
   # In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
    TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     # 'django.contrib.admin',
     # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
     # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
      )
   ```

Please help me.Thanks for your answers
[image: The image of powershell]

Comment: Can we have a glance at your "settings.py" file ? To check your DB content, use the "manage.py inspectdb" command, it should work. I don't know any ".schema" command unfortunatly.. Here is the manage.py doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

Comment: @Ricola3D i have added settings.py.The .schema command is in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/ under database setup  topic

Comment: @AnazA Post some code here. Not screenshots.

Comment: @arulmr  pasted some more codes

Comment: @Ricola3D pasted the codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Django can't set-up the DB.

Try to replace:

```
'NAME': 'C:\\Eclipse\\workspace\\mysite\\src\\sqlite.db',
```

By:

```
'NAME': 'sqlite.db',
```

In your settings.py.

It could be a path problem.

You should also check the directory permissions to be sure that Django can write the DB to it. I have no experience with Windows regarding this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a WAMP server, why don't you use mysql instate of sqlite?